# Should I set the projection if the data has already been projected?

Tags: qgis, gdal, coordinate-system, pyqgis

I need to plot some data which was produced on a native grid  with a lambert conformal conic projection. I need to create a geotiff (using python and gdal) and was wondering how to go about and do this. I have been told the following:

> Is your data on a native grid? A native grid is a model that was
>   designed from the beginning with a particular map projection. In order
>   to plot the data exactly as the designers planned, we do not want to
>   transform the data to a projection, but simply plot it. This is the
>   essence of the examples on this page.
>
> Just because your data has 2D lat/lon arrays, does not make it a
>   native grid. Native grids are plotted differently than other data with
>   2D coordinates.

from: https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/lcnative.shtml

The dataset comprises of a set of gridded data which were produced on a lcc grid. The guide states:

> In order
>   to plot the data exactly as the designers planned, we do not want to
>   transform the data to a projection, but simply plot it.`

How can I make a geotiff and what spatial and projection information should I use? The image xs and ys I have are in degrees but the grid spacing for xs and ys were difined in metres.